# Check proof that $h(x) = a\sin{p_1x\over q_1}+b\cos{p_2x \over q_2}$ is periodic and find its period

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, proof-verification

I'm trying to:

> Find period of $a\sin{p_1x\over q_1}+b\cos{p_2x \over q_2}$ where $p_1, p_2, q_1, q_2 \in \mathbb N$ and $p_1q_2\ne p_2q_1$

Let: 
$$
f(x) = a\sin{p_1x\over q_1} \\
g(x) = b\cos{p_2x \over q_2}
$$

Then period of $f(x)$ is $T_f =2\pi {q_1\over p_1}$ and period of $g(x)$ is $T_g = 2\pi {q_2\over p_2}$. Let ${q_1 \over p_1} = n_0$ and ${q_2 \over p_2} = m_0$. So we have:

$$
T_f = 2\pi n_0\\
T_g = 2\pi m_0
$$

Consider $h(x) = f(x) + g(x)$:

$$
h(x) = h(x+2\pi m_0n_0) = f(x+2\pi m_0n_0) + g(x+2\pi m_0n_0)
$$

Therefore: 
$$
T_h = 2\pi m_0n_0 = 2\pi m_0{q_1 \over p_1} = 2\pi n_0{q_2 \over p_2}
$$

I'm learning math myself and have nobody to refer to. Could someone tell me whether the above is a correct way of solving that problem?

Comment: The period is the smallest 'repeating unit'. What you have shown is that the period is at most $2π m_0 n_0$, but it could be smaller.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Is there a way to show that some period it's the smallest one?

Comment: I suggest considering this quantity divided some integer >1, by looking at the factors of the related quantities you should be able to prove that no such number is the period. PS The notation $n_0,m_0$ suggests that they are integers, but they aren't (necessarily)

Comment: Try to write the expression as a single $sin$ or $cos$ function.